Setting Azure DevOps Pre-deployement conditions when creating CI/CD pipelines with yaml templates on Azure Data Factory
I have successfully created a CI/CD pipeline for Azure Data Factory with Azure DevOps using yaml templates, see below. This in contrast to creating the same pipelines using Azure DevOps 'Classic Editor'
When creating Build/Release pipelines using Classic Editor I have the option to create Pre-Deployment options such as shown in the image - in particular I would like to setup 'Pre-deployment approvals.

Is there a similar option to choose Pre-deployment approvals from any of the following yaml templates:

My yaml code is as follows:
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  displayName: Show file structure of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory during a build


- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    displayName: PreDeployment
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'NewConnectionName'
    subscriptionId: '5fa2700d-738a-444e-a643-28241a29d08d'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroup)'
    location: '$(Location)'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName $(DataFactory)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'


- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup)  -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $false -deleteDeployment $true'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

I was thinking that one of the following task could be used to pause a the pipeline until some intervention was approved

But I couldn't get either of the above to tasks to work inside my yaml
I get the error
Job Job: Step references task 'ManualIntervention' at version '8.238.0' which is not valid for the given job target.

I have tried the following yaml code I found online
jobs:
- job: waitForValidation
  displayName: Wait for external validation  
  pool: server    
  timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
  steps:   
   - task: ManualValidation@0
     timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
     inputs:
         notifyUsers: |
            someone@example.com
         instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
         onTimeout: 'resume'

But I get the following error:
/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/azure-pipelines-5.yml (Line: 77, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'jobs'

I have updated the yaml code to reflect the code that @Vlad kindly helped me with:
trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  displayName: Show file structure of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory during a build

- task: ManualValidation@0
  timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
  inputs:
      notifyUsers: |
          someone@example.com
      instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
      onTimeout: 'resume'

However, I'm still getting the error:
Job Job: Step references task 'ManualValidation' at version '0.238.0' which is not valid for the given job target.

There is probably something very obvious that I'm missing, but I can't see it.

An alternative option is to have a yaml template that provides the same approval functionality as a Git pull requeset - but not if that exists?

In YAML pipelines, you can configure manually approvals like as below:

If the stage contains deploy jobs that need to target to environments, You can directly set approvals on the environments. If you have set multiple approval checks on the environment, you can change execution order of the checks to let then evaluate as Pre-check approval or Post-check approval.


If the stage does not contain any deploy jobs, you can configure a Server job (Agentless job) to run the ManualValidation@0 task.

Add the a Server job as the first job in the stage and let other jobs depend on it.
Add a ManualValidation@0 task in the Server job to pause a the YAML pipeline run to wait for manual approval.



stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: approvalsA
    displayName: 'Manual Approvals'
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440  # Set time out.
      inputs:
      # You can add multiple approvers.
        notifyUsers: |
          user1@example.com
          user3@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate and approve the run on this stage.'

  - job: A1
    dependsOn: approvalsA
    steps:
    . . .

  - job: A2
    dependsOn: approvalsA
    steps:
    . . .

- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: approvalsB
    displayName: 'Manual Approvals'
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          user1@example.com
          user3@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate and approve the run on this stage.'

  - job: B1
    dependsOn: approvalsB
    steps:
    . . .

  - job: B2
    dependsOn: approvalsB
    steps:
    . . .



Hi @Bright, I haven't had a chance to implement your suggestion, but it looks spot on. Thank you. I will let you know how I get on.

its looking good so far. Just a quick question. Is there a yaml template for 'Stage', 'jobs', 'job' etc.? There is a yaml template for 'ManualValidation@0


Error says: Unexpected value 'jobs'.

For ManualValidation you have used a snippet with structure:
jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - task

But in your original pipeline you only have structure:
steps:
  - task

If in the beginning of the pipeline definition you use steps without stages and jobs, it means that you are implicitly skipping the jobs level and define only one single job.

You should check out key concepts of Azure Pipelines to understand it better.
Key concepts


Image from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops
Concepts:

A trigger tells a pipeline to run.
A pipeline is made up of one or more stages. A pipeline can deploy to one or more environments.
A stage is a way of organizing jobs in a pipeline and each stage can have one or more jobs.
Each job runs on one agent. A job can also be agentless.
Each agent runs a job that contains one or more steps.
A step can be a task or script and is the smallest building block of a pipeline.
A task is a prepackaged script that performs an action, such as invoking a REST API or publishing a build artifact.



Something like this should work:
trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  displayName: Show file structure of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory during a build

# Steps before manual approval
# ...

- task: ManualValidation@0
     timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
     inputs:
         notifyUsers: |
            someone@example.com
         instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
         onTimeout: 'resume'

# Steps after manual approval
# ...



Hi @Vlad, thanks for reaching out - really appreciate it. I have updated the question to show that I'm still getting the error, even with the code you provided. I'm clearly missing something

It could be that you can't run it without a job. Try to introduce a job for all the steps before the ManualValidation and a job for all the step after it.
